# NSRegularexpression multiline and stack

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I can't find a regular expression having balanced tags, one for opening and one for closing. 
Tags must enclose multi lines text; and tags are dynamic, not defined at compile time

I can't match the closing tag corresponding to the opening tag, for instance {{home}} -> {{/home}} and {{hello}} -> {{/hello}}; it match {{home}} to {{/hello}}
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Any help will be greatly appreciated

gregoire

ps : I commented non working regexp

```
    NSString * string;
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression* regex;
    NSArray* matches;


    string =
    @" The {{demo}}following tables describe the {{/demo}}character expressions"
    " used by the regular expression to match patterns within "
    " a string,{{home}} the pattern operators that specify how many"
    " times a pattern is matched and additional matching"
    " restrictions, and the last {{/home}}table specifies flags"
    " that can be included in the regular ";


    regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:
             @"\\{\\{demo\\}\\}"
             "(.*)?"
             "\\{\\{(//|/demo)\\}\\}"
                                                      options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators
                                                        error:&error];


//    regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:
//             @"\\{\\{.*\\}\\}"
//             "(.*)?"
//             "\\{\\{(//|/.*)\\}\\}"
//                                                      options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators
//                                                        error:&error];


    matches = [regex matchesInString:string
                             options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators
                               range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    for ( NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches )
    {
        NSLog(@"### %@ ###", [string substringWithRange:[match range]]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern

```
\{\{([^/]*?)\}\}(.*?)\{\{(/\1|//)\}\}
    -------     ----     --------
       |          |          |->matches closing tag having value same as group 1 or //
       |          |->content in group 2
       |->matches the opening tag value and captures it in group1
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I didn't know / find the concept of groups. It's working well except I made a little changement for multi listes :              @"\\{\\{([^/]*?)\\}\\}"
".*?" (here is the change)
"\\{\\{((/\\1)|(//))\\}\\}"